# Syntax to merge multiple rows into multiple columns instead

Tags: mysql, select

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do a join to convert multiple rows into columns.  In the example query below, the results are turning multiple rows for each request_id.  Instead, I'd like to have one row per unique request_id with columns for each of the other values.

Would be really grateful for any assistance!

```
SELECT r.REQUEST_ID, d.FIELD_ID, f.LABEL_en, d.DATA FROM TABLE_requests as r, TABLE_fields_data as d, TABLE_fields as f WHERE r.REQUEST_ID=d.REQUEST_ID AND f.FIELD_ID=d.FIELD_ID;
```

```
REQUEST_ID   FIELD_ID.    LABEL_en.         DATA
47           2            Arrival Date      2018-08-11
47           3            Departure Date    2018-08-12
47           4            Guest First Name  Daniel
47           5            Guest Last Name   Smith
48           2            Arrival Date      2018-06-06
48           3            Departure Date    2018-05-08
48           4            Guest First Name  Joseph
48           5            Guest Last Name   Client
49           2            Arrival Date      2018-06-08
49           3            Departure Date.   2018-06-09
49           4            Guest First Name  Alberto
49           5            Guest Last Name   Customer
```

```
REQUEST_ID   FIELD_ID.    LABEL_en.         DATA.        LABEL_en.        DATA.       
47           2            Arrival Date      2018-08-11.  Departure Date.  2018-08-12
```

Comment: Does every request_id always have four label_en values?

Comment: BTW `FROM TABLE_requests as r, TABLE_fields_data as d, TABLE_fields as f`  that legacy join syntax is outdated for 30 years now. Use explicit joins.

Comment: @SamM In this case, yes.  But ideally I would specify the FIELD_ID's I'd like to pull.